# Inefficient saving with hibernate using a manyToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a list with 25 MyApplication objects that I want to save using hibernate/JPA. This is done with the following method:

```
MyApplicationRepository.saveAll(myAppList);
```

However I noticed that hibernate creates over 60.000 MyApplication objects (close to the total amount of records already in database for this entity) while inserting/updating this list of 25 in the database. I don't have a lot of hibernate experience which leads me to believe I created a inefficient entity relations. A part of the MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "APPLICATION_CATEGORY", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "applicationid", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "categoryid",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Category> categorySet;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myApplication", 
                  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Screenshot> screenshotSet;
}
```

Category class (one example of multiple of the many to many relations of MyApplication):

```
public class Category {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categorySet")
    private Set<MyApplication> myApplicationSet;
}
```

Screenshot class:

```
public class Screenshot {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationid")
    private MyApplication myApplication;
}
```

What did I do wrong that resulted in Hibernate creating so many instances of MyApplication when saving?

Note 1: In the end all of the information of MyApplication and the information of it's categories and screenshots is saved correctly in the database.

Note 2: It's important that not only MyApplication is saved but also everything from all its categories and screenshots as well.

Comment: How did yoe come to the conclusion that Hibernate created 60,000 instances of MyApplication when saving 25 existing instances of MyApplication? Show your experiment, with inputs and outputs, that proves that weird assertion.

Comment: @JB Nizet I added a static counter to MyApplication that increased by one for everytime the constructor was called. Then I used my debugger to check the count before and after the save.

Comment: Also note that the app goes from 500 MB to 4 GB RAM when it starts saving, this was not an issue when my database was pretty empty but currently I have around 100k MyApplication records so I assume Hibernate is querying a lot of those based on categories that are shared with the instance I am trying to insert/update

Comment: Missing indexes? Are you fetching and re-saving all the entities in the database? (because you say it was fast when empty)

Comment: I just did a test with an application that has 5 categories and no other objects (e.g. screenshots, etc.) and can verify that the amount of object constructs was 58.981, when I queried my database for all applications that were linked to one of these 5 categories, I got 58.979 rows so I'm quite sure that Hibernate is selecting all the applications linked to every category. I don't have any indexes outside of the hibernate defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. The problem was caused by the bidirectional nature of the manyToMany relation. This resulted in the category also querying all the applications from the database before saving. As this is not what I want, I resolved the issue by turning it into a unidirectional relation by removing the myApplicationSet from the Category class. Now only 25 MyApplication instances are constructed to save 25 applications and my memory usage remains stable.